# Mitigate MS17-010 on Windows XP? (wannacry ransomware)

Tags: exploit, windows-xp

On my network I have to run two XP VM, because of legacy programs.

How can I mitigate MS17-010 on Windows XP? The machines are not directly exposed to internet, but they must be connected to the LAN.

Is enough to disable SMB server for avoid having my VM infected? I don't need a SMB server on the machine, but I need to access SMB clients from it.

Comment: See directly from Microsoft [Customer Guidance for WannaCrypt attacks](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msrc/2017/05/12/customer-guidance-for-wannacrypt-attacks/) where they even provided patches for  unsupported systems like Windows XP.

Comment: "Is enough to disable SMB server for avoid having my VM infected? I don't need a SMB server on the machine..."  In addition to some of the answers below, it's worth noting that it would be wise to disable any services that aren't explicitly needed. That's always a good move in my opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microsoft released patches for all operating systems in *custom support*. Please see [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msrc/2017/05/12/customer-guidance-for-wannacrypt-attacks/).

For English language patches, direct links are [Windows XP SP2 x64](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/csa/csa/secu/2017/02/windowsserver2003-kb4012598-x64-custom-enu_f24d8723f246145524b9030e4752c96430981211.exe) and [Windows XP SP3 x86](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/csa/csa/secu/2017/02/windowsxp-kb4012598-x86-custom-enu_eceb7d5023bbb23c0dc633e46b9c2f14fa6ee9dd.exe). Localized version of the patch can be found [here](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4012598). Rest of the links can be found on the bottom of the blog post.

Comment: The linked blog post specifically states that Microsoft "made the decision to make the Security Update for **platforms in custom support only** (...) broadly available for download" (my emphasis). "Custom support only" is very different from "unsupported".

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That is technically true but majority of users of these operating systems will not receive updates anymore. From their perspective they are de facto unsupported. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I tried to install the localised update for Windows XP SP3 x86 (Greek) and it failed stating that the update language does not match the os language. What gives? I downloaded the update from the stated form and I also tried downloading from the Catalog Update site but same result.

Comment: @h1k3n That's a very different question from what this is asking. You might try asking on [su].

Answer (score 4):

There is a MS17-010 patch for Windows XP Embedded systems that fits the regular Windows XP.   You can download it at the link below:

http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/search.aspx?q=4012598

Google for the "POSready" string to learn how to install this Windows XP Embedded patch on a regular Windows XP.